# how can i horizontally justify this menu

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Hi guys if you can tell me how can i make the menu justified when minimising he browser window till 768px breakpoint. I tried using display flex but i dont know how to make it responsive.

[This is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BFE7/1/)

```
.menu_container {
min-height: 41px;
clear: both;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Comment: Can you say more? Do you want the menu not to flow out of view? Do you want to scroll? Is it the width or the height that's bothering you?

Comment: And could you by any change only add in the jsFiddle the needed code for the specified breaking point scenario ?

Comment: im sorry for the messy code will just add the required one. I need the menu to be justified from left to right. even when i make the browser window smaller. height is not the problem width is the problem

Comment: When you say "justified" do you mean centered? http://jsfiddle.net/M5h7h/

Comment: What do you mean "justified"? You have sub menus are you after them to be on there too?